# For Simple Gambler's ruin (fair coin flipping), how does one derive the formulas $ P_{1}=\dfrac {n_{2}}{n_{1}+n_{2}}$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I was looking at this problem: A has 6 dollars and B has 4 dollars. They bet one dollar each time by flipping an unbiased coin until one of them runs out of money. What is the probability of A winning all the money.

And I wanted to understand the general result:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Fair_coin_flipping

The wiki page has an outline of the proof for the more complicated case of unfair coin flipping. I wish to know how to derive the solution, where if player one has n1 pennies and player two n2 pennies, the probabilities P for fair coin flipping, 
P1 and P2 that players one and two, respectively, will end penniless are: $   P_{1}=\dfrac {n_{2}}{n_{1}+n_{2}}, P_{2}=\dfrac {n_{1}}{n_{2}+n_{1}} $

The recurrence relation, where $q_{n}= P(R_{n})$ is $ q_{n} = 1/2(q_{n+1}+q_{n-1})$.
And it is obvious that $q_{(n1+n2)/2}=1/2, q_{0} = 1, q_{n1+n2}=0 $

I feel there is something obvious I am missing, because of the symmetry when n1 = n2, so in the example player A and B have 5 dollars it is obviously 1/2 each. Do I have to solve the recurrence relation some how?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n$ be the number of coins $A$ has after $n$ flips, so $A_0=n_1$ and $A_{n+1}=A_n\pm1$. Then 
$$
\mathbb E[A_{n+1}|A_n]=A_n\tag{1}
$$
and extending the above, we see that $$\mathbb E[A_n]=\mathbb E[A_0]=n_1,\tag{2}$$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Let $t$ be the number of flips it takes for either $A$ or $B$ to win all the money, so $t$ is a random variable (known as a *stopping time*). You can show that $(2)$ holds for $n=t$, so that $$\mathbb E[A_t]=n_1.$$ But there is another way to calculate $\mathbb E[A_t]$. Let $p$ be the probability that $a$ ends up with all the money. Then
$$
\mathbb E[A_t]=p\cdot (n_1+n_2)+(1-p)\cdot 0,
$$
because $A_t$ is equal to either all the money or none of it with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$. Combining this last equation with $\mathbb E[A_t]=n_1$ implies $p=n_1/(n_1+n_2)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "and extending above"?