# Limiting distribution of Markov chain with transient and recurrent class

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stationary-processes

Consider the following transition probability matrix P with the state space
 S = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

P:

```
|1   0   0    0    0| 
|0.5 0   0.5  0    0|
|0   0.5 0    0.5  0|
|0   0   0.5  0  0.5|
|0   0   0    0    1|
```

Classes are  {0}, {1,2,3}, {4} where 0 and 4 are recurrent whereas 1,2,3 is transient .
Find lim n→∞ p(n)ij , for all i, j ∈ S
How do I find the limiting distribution for these type of matrices which are a mixture of transient and recurrent?
It will be very helpful if someone gives the link to more problems of this type.

Comment: Use that $p^{(n)}_{ij}$ is the probability that starting from $i$, after $n$ steps, you are at site $j$ and think about what this chain is doing.

Comment: This Markov chain models the [Gambler's ruin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Example_of_Huygens's_result) with a fair coin

Comment: The limiting distribution is concentrated on the absorbing states, but since there is more than one of them, it depends on the initial distribution. In this particular case it is the probability distribution of winning/losing in the gambler's ruin problem where the gambler takes his winnings when he earns \$4.

Comment: With my earlier comment in mind, we should find that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P^n = 
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0\\
3/4&0&0&0&1/4\\
1/2&0&0&0&1/2\\
1/4&0&0&0&3/4\\
0&0&0&0&1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain @Omnomnomnom's point and [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Example_of_Huygens's_result) more in detail applying to your question:

First, note that "(i)f player one has $n_1$ pennies and player two $n_2$ pennies, the probabilit(y) $P_1$ ... that players one ... will end penniless (is)":

\begin{aligned}P_{1}&={\frac {n_{2}}{n_{1}+n_{2}}}\\[5pt]\end{aligned}

In your case, it's just like the probability of the first player (first player initally with $n_1$ coins and the second player with $4 - n_2$ coins to start off the game) goes peniness (state $0$) or wins the game (state $4$).

Therefore, if you start off with $0$ coins, since state $0$ is an absorbing state, the probability that you stay at state $0$ is $1$.

If you start off with $1$ coins, that means, your opponent is starting off with $3$ coins, i.e. $n_1 = 1, n_2 = 3$. Plugging this into the equation, yields the probability that the player 1 ends penniless is $\frac{3}{4}$ and the probability that the player 1 wins the game is $\frac{1}{4}$. You can apply the same logic to cases where the player 1 starts off with $2,3$ or $4$ coins.

As to the proof of the equation, you can refer to [Ross' textbook](https://web2.qatar.cmu.edu/~gdicaro/15381-Fall17/additional/Ross-ch4.pdf), Ch 4.5.1 and look at the case where $\frac{p}{q} = 1$

Comment: Or you can refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2790034/for-simple-gamblers-ruin-fair-coin-flipping-how-does-one-derive-the-formulas) for the proof of the formula.